# Getting the "logcat like" from the stack trace Output

Tags: java, android, exception

I'm trying to get the complete exception log "like we have in the android studio"
from the error object that we have in the App class
to be more specific this is my App.java

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDex;

/**
 * Created by informatic on 17/03/2018.
 */

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

 Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler((t, e) -> {
            e.printStackTrace();
            StringBuilder massage=new StringBuilder();
     for (int i = 0; i < e.getStackTrace().length; i++) {
         massage.append(e.getStackTrace()[i].toString());
     }
     String s=massage.toString();
     System.out.print(s);
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

after a NullPointerException this is what the String `s` will contains after the Exception

> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2469)android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151)android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362)android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914)com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:730)dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

but on the other hand the logcat will print this

> com.automata4.www.sanad E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.automata4.www.sanad, PID: 31429
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.automata4.www.sanad/com.automata4.www.sanad.frontend.activities.home.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2469)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:730)
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.automata4.www.sanad.frontend.activities.home.HomeActivity.getAndSetUi(HomeActivity.java:48)
>           at com.automata4.www.sanad.frontend.activities.home.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:42)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5310)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2381)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2469) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

so my question is 
Is there any way to get like the previous output from the `e` object so that I could send this complete exception to my server?